# download a users file from dropbox - javascript

Tags: jquery, api, dropbox

I want to download a file that the user selects from dropbox - so far I have used javascript and the API to list the users files.

When the user selects a file, the only information I have is the path (not the full path, e.g '/getting started.pdf')

The user has already authorized my app to access their file data so I have an access token, but I cant figure out the direct url I need to download the file.

I've been trying to use these urls:

```
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/1/view/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/getting started.pdf
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/getting started.pdf
```

but I always get a 401 not authorized, even when setting the 'Authorization' header. how can I download the file? And, what number is supposed to replace XXXXXXXXXXXXX ?? I've tried both my app id and app secret but nothing seems to work.

the basics of my code are:

```
var access_token = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
var api_secret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX';
var api_key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

$('body').on('click', '.dropbox-doc', function(event){
    var path = $(this).data().path;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/1/view/'+api_key+path+'?dl=1',
        dataType:'json',
        headers: {
            'Authorization':'Bearer '+access_token,
        },
        success: function(data){
            console.log('success')
            console.log(data)
        },
        error: function(data){
            console.log(data)
        }
    });
});
```

I also tried opening the url in a new window instead of ajaxing and I get the same 401 error

Comment: See my reply at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45190200/2603965

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me:

```
// file path example
var path = 'projects/client/design/jpgs/image.jpg';

$.ajax({
  url: 'https://api.dropbox.com/1/media/auto/'+path,
  type: 'POST',
  dataType : 'json',
  headers: {
    'Authorization':'Bearer '+access_token
  },
})
.done(function (data) {
  console.log("success", data);
})
.fail(function (data) {
  console.log("error", data);
})
```

The path you're AJAXing too looks more like the URL that gets returned from this request.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the [official Dropbox JavaScript SDK](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore/sdks/js), you should just use the `readFile` method to download file content from the account of a user who has authorized your app:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore/docs/js#Dropbox.Client.readFile

If you're not using that SDK, you can use the /files (GET) endpoint directly:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#files-GET

This API call needs to be signed using the access token normally. There are some blog posts that cover how to do this normally here:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog/20/using-oauth-10-with-the-plaintext-signature-method
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog/45/using-oauth-20-with-the-core-api

The URLs you have in your question are special kinds of URLs returned by the API, and you shouldn't modify them. Modifying them will cause them to break, because they contain randomly generated tokens (not your app key/secret nor the user's access token).

If you do need to download content via the /1/view/ or /s/ links (which are retrieved via the API using [/media](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#media) and [/shares](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#shares) respectively), e.g., when you don't have the access token, you can do so via a normal network request, without modifying the URL or adding any authorization method.